# Packet Capture in SPARK using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, packet-capture

How to capture packets in SPARK using scala? Is there a library like jpcap in java ? Can anyone please tell me how to write a scala program to capture live packets?

Comment: Spark is for computation, not network debugging. Capture the packets with something else, then come back to Spark when you want to perform large-scale analysis on them.

Comment: scala can use java libraries flawlessly -- use jpcap, as Daniel suggested, to capture traffic, then feed data to spark or whatever tool to analize it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom receiver and use any kind of library or bash command (like calling tshark) to capture the packets and use them as input.

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-custom-receivers.html

Comment: How to pass the packets captured using library into spark streaming? Is it possible to pass them as arguments?

Comment: Since you can give a folder to Spark Streaming as input, you can directly point Spark Streaming to them and read them, best is if they are text files. 
If they are not, I suggest you to feed Spark Streaming with the URI of the files then using some bash command to work with them. 
Didn't really understood what you meant with "as arguments".

Comment: I meant how to pass the packets captured using library directly to Spark Streaming? How would be the structure of receiver program?

Comment: You can view an example of a receiver implemented with a Queue here: 
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/QueueStream.scala

Comment: Thanks. I have Spark 0.9. Here is a sample of receiver that I have written. Is it in this way the Receiver program should be? https://github.com/swe0523/Test-Receiver/blob/master/Receiver

Comment: Think so, have you tried to use it? I've never tried to use Java with Spark.